# How To Sum Tuition of Each Student: What Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq, entity-framework-6

I am developing a ASP.NET MVC 5 Application with EF6. I have about 5000 entities and I'm querying them through LINQ to collect all students with total tuitions:

Models

```
public class Student
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class Payment
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public double Tuition { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; } //Tuition added monthly        
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

for example:

```
student 1:
    {payments{1000}, payments{1500}, payments{3000}}
student 2:
    {payments{400}, payments{1700}, payments{4000}}
...
student n:
    {payments{5000}, payments{6500}, payments{7000}}
```

and query i want is collection of student with total tuition of each student:

```
var result = {{student1, 5500}, {student2, 6100}, ...}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this LINQ query and let EF construct the query a SQL server do the work.

```
context.DbSet<Student>().Select(o => new { 
    Student = o, 
    TotalTution = o.Payments.Sum(p => p. Tution)
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from s in DbContext.Students
            select new {student=s, totalTuition=s.Payments.Sum(p=>p.Tuition)};
```

a readable version if you  prefer less lambdas like me :)